# R: renaming columns from a different dataset

Tags: r, database

I have two data frames:

```
Names =
code meaning
A    Blue
B    Red
C    Green
```

```
df =
id A B C
1  5 7 7
```

I would like to change the column names of df according to the meaning of the data frame Names:

```
Result =
id Blue Red Green
1  5    7   7
```

I am trying to use the function `gsub` but I am not sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `match` to get matching names from  `Names` dataframe. If the names do not match (`id`) keep the original names as it is.

```
names(df) <- dplyr::coalesce(Names$meaning[match(names(df), Names$code)], names(df))
df
#  id Blue Red Green
#1  1    5   7     7
```

---

Using `rename_with` in `dplyr` this can be done as :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% rename_with(~Names$meaning[match(., Names$code)], Names$code)
```

Comment: fab as always.  Just for knowledge can this be written inside `dplyr::rename`?

Comment: Yes, I updated the answer to include an option with `rename_with`.